# ¿En qué países se coloca el pronombre personal justo después de la "palabra qu-" en preguntas?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, cuba

Me parece algo particularmente cubano, pero no estoy seguro, primero, si eso es cierto; segundo, si sólo en Cuba se dice el pronombre personal justo después de la palabra interrogativa. Esta pregunta pide una aclaración al respecto.

**Ejemplo:**

> ¿Cómo *tú* te llamas?
>   ¿Dónde (es que) *tú* vives?

Comment: Bueno chico soy cubano y el ejemplo que **tú** pones es la manera en que yo lo digo, ¿Hay otra manera de decirlo? :) lo último fue una pregunta retórica

Comment: @EmilioGort Gracias, entonces no estoy tan equivocado. Mejor formulada, mi pregunta sería: ¿Sólo en Cuba se pregunta así?

Comment: Vaya, qué curioso, es cómo en francés.

Comment: @JoulSauron And ... Where do **you** live? :)

Comment: http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espa%C3%B1ol_cubano

Answer (score 6):

No se limitaría solo en las preguntas sino en el habla.

[Centro Virtual Cervantes (CVC): Cuba](http://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/voces_hispanicas/cuba/la_habana.htm)

> Plano gramatical
>
> - Tuteo y sistema de tratamiento con ustedes para la segunda persona del plural.
> - Tendencia al orden Sujeto-Verbo-Objeto, con anteposición del sujeto en interrogativas y ante infinitivos: ¿qué tú quieres?, ¿dónde tú vives?; sonreí al tú decirme eso; él lo hizo todo para yo poder descansar.
> - Tendencia a uso expreso de pronombre personal sujeto: ¿tú te quedas o tú te vas?

Y según la RAE [pronombres personales tónicos](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=pronombres+personales+t%C3%B3nicos)

> En ciertas variedades del español, con especial incidencia en el habla caribeña, **la -s final se aspira, se debilita o se pierde, de manera que la segunda persona del singular puede llegar a converger oralmente con las formas de primera y de tercera**, según los tiempos, lo que justifica la frecuencia con la que se hace explícito, en esas zonas, el sujeto tú: «¿Qué tú quieres más que eso?» (González Provisiones [Cuba 1975]).

Como dice el párrafo anterior por la aspiración de la -s *Dónde vives?* puede ser fácilmente oída como *Dónde vive?* (tercera persona) de ahí que añadan el tú *¿Dónde tú vives?*.

Muchos países de la cuenca se vieron influenciados por el español caribeño, como por ejemplo el español costeño de Colombia.

[Español costeño](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regi%C3%B3n_Caribe_(Colombia)#Dialecto_y_lenguas)

> La aspiración de la /s/ antes de consonante y su pérdida al final de palabra.

[Español caribeño](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espa%C3%B1ol_caribe%C3%B1o)

> Se habla en los territorios isleños de Cuba, la República Dominicana, Puerto Rico, y en territorios continentales de Colombia, Venezuela y Panamá.(*)

(*) Más en la zona costeña del territorio continental.

Más enlaces del CVC lo corroboran

- [Santo Domingo (República Dominicana)](http://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/voces_hispanicas/republicadominicana/santodomingo.htm)
- [San Juan (Puerto Rico)](http://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/voces_hispanicas/puertorico/sanjuan.htm)

Como dicen los cantantes Pitbull o Notch: ya tu sabe! *Nota: Lo usan en la música aunque no se si tomarlo como ejemplo real de esta habla.*

Comment: El ya tu sabe!, asi es como lo he pronuciado toda la vida, pitbull es hijo de cubanos y crecio en miami donde hay una comunidad muy grande de cubanos, cuando estube en colombia, en la parte del valle se me hacia muy dificil la comunicacion, decian que yo hablaba muy fuerte.

Comment: @Emilio Gort Perfecto. Como ambos son músicos y por sus orígenes no sabía si habían modificado la expresión como algunos intérpretes raperos hacen.

Answer (score 1):

Ésta forma es usada principalmente en países de la órbita centroamericana y algunos países sudamericanos, pero en menor medida, como tú dices, es cierto que en Cuba se utiliza mucho y es una expresión menos común en otros países.

Answer (score 0):

Aquella manera de hablar se utiliza en países centroamericanos. Aquí, en Chile, nadie habla de aquella manera, a menos que sea... centroamericano ^_^
Hace unos años, Canal 13 (un canal chileno) emitió una teleserie ambientada en Costa Rica, *Don Amor* (una referencia a Don Omar), y, en ella, se nota mucho la diferencia entre el español chileno y el costarricense. A mí, como chilena, a veces me cuesta entender los acentos centroamericanos, además, allí se utiliza el *spanglish*, debido a la cercanía con Estados Unidos.